# KivyMD - Python - How to add new widgets on the screen dynamicaly?

Tags: python, dynamic, widget, kivy, screen

I'm the very beginner in python and that is my first application and I still haven't learnd much, so please don't judge me for not smart code (I write almost all in one heap, sorry for that).

The main idea of application was in remining the user to do some activities, e.g. drink water, take medicine and see that all in a calendar (you'll see it on screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5jTH.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8KpI.png)), but at first I want to make a "Take Medicine" part - it has to calculate how many days the user have to take pills if he/she knows how many pills they have and how many times a day they have to take them.

I've created two screens: Main for displaying the objects and Second to create that widgets. Now I want to fill all the data on the Second screen and add the widget with that data to the Main screen. Maybe I should use MDCards or Lists? But I really have no idea how to do it all.

Should I create database to add data there and then create new widgets on the Main screen according to that and if yes so how? And how to create and represent that widgets dynamicaly? Maybe I have to create function that will somehow add widgets to the 2nd tab on Main screen, but where and how slould I implement it?

Really hope for your help because it's my project for university programming course but my professor doesn't want to help students at all so i have no one else to ask.

So it's **main.py**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class ScreensManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Do Not Forget"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        Window.size = (1080 / 3.4, 2280 / 3.4)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return ScreensManager() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And **my.kv**

```
<ScreensManager>:
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen1'
                text: 'active'
                icon: 'note-plus'

                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .85, "center_y": .075}
                    icon: 'plus'
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

                    #this is uncompleted part, doesn't matter for now
                    #on_release:
                    #   app.root.current = "third_screen"
                    #   root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen2'
                text: 'medicine'
                icon: 'pill'

                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .85, "center_y": .075}
                    icon: 'plus'
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "second_screen"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen3'
                text: 'calendar'
                icon: 'calendar'


<SecondScreen>:
    name: "second_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 20

            MDLabel:
                text: "Insert your data"

            Widget:

            MDLabel:
                text:"Name of medicine"

            MDTextField:
                id: name_med
                hint_text: "Name"
                mode: "rectangle"

            Widget:

            MDLabel:
                text:"How many pills do you have?"

            MDTextField:
                id: pills_amount
                hint_text: "Pills amount"
                mode: "rectangle"

            Widget:

            MDLabel:
                text:"How many times a day to take them?"

            MDTextField:
                id: times_amount
                hint_text: "Times a day"
                mode: "rectangle"

        FloatLayout:
            MDFloatingActionButton:
                pos_hint:{"center_x": .2, "center_y": .2}
                icon: 'arrow-left'
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main_screen"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

            MDFloatingActionButton:
                pos_hint:{"center_x": .8, "center_y": .2}
                icon: 'check'
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main_screen"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use BoxLayout, you should use Grid Layout which should perfectly answer your problematic.

Here is the Kivy doc about that :

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html

and an example of dynamic creation (a bit hard but you could try to reverse-engineering it!)

[Dynamic grid in Kivy with each grid element containing multiple widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039728/dynamic-grid-in-kivy-with-each-grid-element-containing-multiple-widgets)

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the information, it helps but the main problem was not in this. I don't know how to create a new widget after pressing the button. Recently I've tried to do function in a new class that i locate inside of that GridLayout but nothing creating when i press that button and I'm not sure why

Comment: Does it answer your 2nd question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577828/kivy-dynamically-add-custom-widget-to-layout-via-python